# python print double Bracket "{{}}" using .format on it

Tags: python, string, printing, string.format

By using `print("""{{1}} {}""".format("x"))` I want to print this:

> **{{1}} x**

But I get this:

> {1} x

But after using `print("""{{{1}}} {}""".format("x"))`(three brackets rather than two) I get `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

So how can I print double brackets using .format on it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quadruple brackets `print("""{{{{1}}}} {}""".format("x"))` as double bracket prints one bracket in output so 4 prints two